# GCM /topics/global works, but to register_id doesn't

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, http-status-code-400

I am working on a GCM project. Everything works when I use the parameter to send the message to all devices. However, I want the message to go to one specific device using the registration_id. As far as I can read in the documentation, I'm doing as I am supposed to do.

When I use `"to":"/topics/global"` it works as seen below:

```
  JSONObject jGcmData = new JSONObject();
  JSONObject jData = new JSONObject();

  jData.put("message", customer.getToken());

  jGcmData.put("to", "/topics/global");
  jGcmData.put("data", jData);

  URL url = new URL("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
  HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
  conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "key=" + API_KEY);
  conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
  conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
  conn.setDoOutput(true);

  OutputStream outputStream = conn.getOutputStream();
  outputStream.write(jGcmData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

.. But this one **does not**

```
  // Send to specified phone (id taken from database)
  jGcmData.put("to", customer.getPhoneId());
```

This is the error log:

```
  java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1839)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1440)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
        at com.fenrir.webservice.Gcm.GcmSender.sendMessage(GcmSender.java:52)
        at com.fenrir.webservice.Controller.CustomerController.user(CustomerController.java:27)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1521)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1478)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Is the documentation deprecated? How can I figure out what is wrong with my jSonObject?

Comment: Maybe you could print out `customer.getPhoneId()` and `jGcmData.toString()` to see if there are any json issues. You might also want to use curl requests for comparison. Lastly, try it with `https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send` in the URL.

Comment: @Koh Thanks for the response. I tried both your suggestions, but no success so far. The output with jGcmData.toString() is as followed: `jGcmData = {"data":{"message":"1pl1ho"},"to":"dowaoEM3xwA:APA91bGsWBSyYnqGZw3ody_gC_A2Uxa8qIMUi7"}`, seems right to me. Strange that I can not find anything in the documentation how you would send a message to one specific id.